# Load resource from classpath when resource name contains special chars

Tags: java, encoding, special-characters, classloader

I want to get the absolute file path for a resource thats in the classpath.

This working pretty well unless the **resource name contains specials chars** like german umlauts:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myresourceÄÖÜ(test).pdf");
```

The returned url is always null although the resource does exist (i can load them if i change the name to not contain specials chars).

I tested already different file.encoding and sun.jnu.encoding settings (set them both to UTF-8), but no luck ...

Environment: Linux and Windows with Oracle Java 1.7/1.8. 
On OS X this is surprisingly working well.

Comment: What happens if you (just for test) rename your resource using plain English letters only?

Comment: @AlexR then it works well

Comment: Your example works for me. The only difference is that I added leading `/` because my class is in package but resource is in root. BTW I tried files with Russian and Hebrew names also. Everything is working fine. Please double check the location of your file and add `/` if it is in root.

Comment: thanks. On Mac its also working for me, but not on Win or Linux (and i don't see the difference). Whats your env?

Comment: R U sure that you try _exactly_ the same test? Is there a chance that you run your test from IDE?

Comment: It seems that default charset in your system is not UTF-8 as on mine. This was the reason.

Comment: Solved: "ÄÜÖ" sequence file name in bytes: [-61, -124, -61, -100, -61, -106] and in code [65, -52, -120, 85, -52, -120, 79, -52, -120]